# Why is moveByOffset() not working for multiple navigation?

Tags: selenium

Passing coordinates and move the cursor at specified coordinates. When I navigating for second time it's not working

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.move_by_offset(x_axis,y_axis).click().perform()

actions.release().perform()

driver.get_screenshot_as_file(destination)
```

So, I tried initializing web-driver for every click, and it works:

```
clickCoordinate(browser,869, 95,dest1)
url=browser.current_url
try:
    browser = get_selenium_driver()
    browser.get(url)
except Exception as err:
    logger.error("Error compiling data: %s", err)
    clickCoordinate(browser,1047, 60,dest2)
```

Please advice on how to achieve that without having to initialize every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet of code is working for me.
Calculate current co-ordinates minus previous co-ordinates and store into variables, here it is axis_x and axis_y and then apply move_by_offset and pass axis_x and axis_y to navigate multiple times

axis_x = curr_x - prev_x

axis_y = curr_y - prev_y

actions.move_by_offset(axis_x,axis_y).click().perform()

Comment: You're doing this in a loop, I know it's year+ later, can you post more code as to how you got this working?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it's because move_by_offset() is moving relative to the current position of the cursor. What I've done with success for absolute coordinates is `actions.move_to_element_with_offset(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body'), x_axis,y_axis)` which will always be in respect to the top left of the page because that's where the body element starts.

Comment: Thanks Dean W for your quick response but I don't want to use element , without giving element I want absolute cordinate

Comment: There's not a built-in way to move to absolute coordinates or to reset the cursor coordinates to 0,0. The body element should always be present in the DOM and should always encompass the entire page, so it is a suitable workaround for absolute coordinates in my experience. Is there any reason why using an element is unsuitable to your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is related to mouse coordinate reset. this can be solved by resetting the coordinate everytime to 0,0 before setting next page coordinate.